# Java Wrapper enum switch polymorphism

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, polymorphism, wrapper

I have this code with using Wrapper, from original interface. On bases enums a will call the methods of linked list, like putFirst(T data), putCurrent(T data), putLast(), removeFirst(), ...

```
...

@Override
public void put(T data, EnumPosition position) {

    switch (position) {
        case FIRST:
            abstrList.putFirst();
            break;

        case LAST:
            abstrList.putLast();
            break;

        ...

        default:
           throw new NoSuchElementException("something exception...");
    }

@Override
public void remove(T data, EnumPosition position) {

    switch (position) {
        case FIRST:
            abstrList.removeFirst(data);
            break;

        case LAST:
            abstrList.removeLast(data);
            break;

        ...

        default:
           throw new NoSuchElementException("something exception...");
    }
```

My EnumPosition now looks simple. (is possible change it implement some interface)

```
public enum EnumPosition {
     FIRST, LAST, CURRENT ...
```

}

A would like to ask, if is possible remove this switch and replace it some polymorphism, consumer with lambda in java 8 or other... Something more effective.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. However the answer depends on how you use your enum.

Do you always pass in the same enum value over and over or do they get mixed up?

**If you always use the same enum**

You can make multiple wrapper implementations that take the `List` and make a factory that takes the enum to determine the implementation (or make it a factory method on the enum itself).

```
MyList<T> list = EnumPosition.LAST.newMyListWrapper(abstrList);

list.put(data);
list.remove(data);
```

**If you mix up your enums in your call**

If you use different enums at the same time to act on the same `abstrList` then you will have to add `put(List<T> list, T data)` and `remove(List<T> list, data)` methods to your enum:

```
EnumPosition.LAST.put(abstrList, data);

EnumPosition.CURRENT.remove(abstrList, data);
```

Or you can do both if you need to support both use cases...

Answer (score 1):

What about enum state machine? I'm not sure if it will fix Your problem, but You can try edit Your interface like this:

```
    public enum EnumPosition {
    FIRST {
      @Override
      public void doPut(){
         abstrList.putFirst();
      }
      @Override
      public void doGet(){
         abstrList.getFirst();
      }
    },
    LAST {
      ... // Override methods for LAST
    },
    CURRENT {
      ...
    },

    ...

    public abstract void doPut();
    public abstract void doGet();
    }
```

After these changes, You can avoid switch using this:

```
...

@Override
public void put(T data, EnumPosition position) {
       position.doPut();
    }
```

You can find more informations here: https://schneide.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/avoid-switch-use-enum/

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't extend enums you can't use polymorphism directly with enums.

But you can define an instance variable in your enum of some type. You can then use polymorphism, e.g.

```
public enum EnumPosition {

    FIRST(new FirstElementModification()), 
    LAST(new LastElementModification())
    ...;

    private ListModification listModification;

    private EnumPosition(ListModification listModification) {
        this.listModification = listModification;
    }

    public <T> void put(List<T> list, T element) {
        listModification.put(list, element);
    }

    public void remove(List<?> list) {
        listModification.remove(list);
    }

}

interface ListModification {
    public <T> void put(List<T> list, T element);
    public <T> void remove(List<T> list);
}
```

and implement the different list modification strategies like this

```
class FirstElementModification implements ListModification {

    public <T> void put(List<T> list, T element) {
        ...
    }

    public <T> void remove(List<T> list) {
        ...
    }

}
```

From the client's perspective you can then ommit the switch and just use

```
EnumPosition.FIRST.put(someList, someElement);
EnumPosition.LAST.remove(someList);
```